# How to get the attribute list of a point that is clicked on the map

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, ux

I would like to double click a point on map and directly getting to its attributes. I'm too lazy to go through the list auf 400 items, just to find it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to View>Toolbar>Check Attribute. Then you will get an info icon in the toolbar. Now load a vector layer and start editing and double click on any feature.

[image: qgis]

Comment: Ohh I even clicked on this when I was searching for a solution. But it was not easy to see that you have to click on the point afterwards. Thank you. That's pretty usefull and easy to do.